# Elixir logger backend: How does system call the init()?

Tags: logging, elixir, backend

I am writing a custom logger backend. I look into other backends, for example :console, LoggerFileBackend, Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP, Logger.Backends.Gelf.

Some of them, for example :console and Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP have init with `{__MODULE__, options}`. Some others like LoggerFileBackend and Logger.Backends.Gelf have init with `{__MODULE__, name}`.

**Question:** How does the system know and call the `init(...)` for backends correctly?
Thank you,
Linh.

Answer (score 3):

I figure out what is going on.
The way we configure the `backends` in the config file will determine how the parameters are passed to the init of the backends.

For example:

```
config :logger,
    backends: [:console ,{LoggerFileBackend, :app_log}, Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP]
```

Then the system will call init as the following:

```
# for console, it will call:
init(:console)

# for LoggerFileBackend, it will call with name set to ":app_log"
init({__MODULE__, name})

# for Timber.LoggerBackends.HTTP, it will call with options omitted
init(__MODULE__, options \\ [])
```